# error 405 get method not allowed

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine

**Angularjs code**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.factory('httpSend', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
     var app = {};
     app.sendToServer = function(data) {
         $http({
             method: "POST",
             url: '/report',
             data: data,
             headers: {
                 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form.urlencoded;'
             }
         }).then(function(response) {
             debugger
             var result = data;
         });
     }
     app.getfromServer = function() {
         var def = $q.defer();
         $http.get('/report').then(function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 def.resolve(data);
             }),
             function(error) {
                 def.reject("Failed to get albums");
             };
         return def.promise;
     }
     return app;
 }]);
 app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'httpSend', '$filter', function($scope, $http, httpSend, $filter) {
     $scope.names = ["ankit patidar", "adhishi ahari", "kritin joshi", "kautilya bharadwaj", "punita ojha", "manvi agarwal", "apeksha purohit", "shipra jain", "mansi nangawat", "praveen soni"];
     $scope.data = [];
     $scope.names.forEach(function(name) {
         $scope.data.push({
             name: name,
             checkin: "",
             checkout: ""
         })
     });
     $scope.login = [];
     $scope.check = function(name, doing) {
         debugger
         name[doing] = new Date();
         name[doing] = $filter('date')(name[doing], 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss');
         $scope.login.push(angular.copy(name));
         if (doing == "checkout") {
             var q = JSON.stringify($scope.login);
             httpSend.sendToServer(q);
         }
     }
     $scope.getData = function() {
         httpSend.getfromServer();
     }
 }]);
```

`

**Python Code**

```
 def get(self):
 logging.info('get is triggered')
 obj = CheckIn.query().fetch()
 emp_obj = []
 for x in obj:
     logging.info('I am inside for loop ')
 emp_obj.append({
     'name': x.name,
     'Check_in': x.inDate,
     'check_out': x.outDate
 })
 logging.info('I am inside emp_obj')
 self.response.write(json.dumps(emp_obj))
```

i need to fetch all the data stored on ndb datastore on front end view thats why i m using http get method but error is showed method not allowed. can u please help e despite using query fetch and showing its response on python ad triggering get method, why error is coming, is there a mistake in control flow or something is missing in my get method, as for now i m able to post nd store data

Comment: Don't use the var app = {}; for your factory logic and change x-www-form.urlencoded to json.Change the name of var app in ur factory logic

Comment: instead of var app={} what to use??? and changing the content type also, no changes are there, showing the same error

Comment: You can use any other name. You are loading your angular module on var app. So its better if you use any other variable name for your factory logic.

Comment: thnks, it helped me to move atleast one step forward with a new error

Comment: Great, What error are you getting now? BTW var result = data; should be changed to var result = response.data;

Comment: typeError: httpSend.sendToServer is not a function and httpsend.getfromserver is not a function

Comment: Upvote answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change your factory to the following. Don't use the same variable app that you are using for initialising your module for your controller logic.

```
app.factory('httpSend',['$http', '$q',function($http, $q){
  return {
    'sendToServer': function(data) {
      var def = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/report',
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            debugger
            var result = response.data;
            def.resolve(result );
        });
          return def.promise;
    },
    'getfromServer': function() {
        var def = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/report').then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                def.resolve(data);
            }),
            function(error) {
                def.reject("Failed to get albums");
            };
        return def.promise;
    }
}
        }]);
```